# Only dummy audio device for simultaneous login session on Debian 12

Tags: linux, debian, pipewire

I upgraded on my laptop to Debian 12 from 11. Audio works fine for the first user being logged in. If I log out with that first user, I can log in with another, and audio works fine for the newly logged-in user.

However, if I log in with a second user while someone is still logged in, the second user does not get audio, and `pavucontrol` reports no input devices and just a dummy output device.

It seems that the first user's session is somehow "locking" access to the sound card for the other session. Clearing `~/. config/pulse` and logout-login does not solve the problem.

I am using Gnome with all users.

---

If I `sudo killall pipewire`, I can sometimes get access to audio, and the real audio device will show up in `pavucontrol`; in those cases, the fist user loses access to sound and only gets a dummy device.

My question is: How can I enable true multiuser sound access on my system, so if I just switch between users then I can use sound immediately? Or maybe even simultaneously?